# what is identityMapCapacity means in schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

What does the `identityMapCapacity` means in Confluent Schema Registry `CachedSchemaRegistryClient`. As per the documentation its declaration is like:

```
public CachedSchemaRegistryClient(@NotNull String baseUrl,int identityMapCapacity)
```

I saw couple of posts where it is initialized with `int` 10 and somewhere it is 1000. So I am not sure what exactly it means and what should I use.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of CachedSchemaRegistryClient, a schemaCache map is created that stores subject as key and a map of schema/Id as value. identityMapCapacity is meant for capping the number of schema objects that can be there in the schema/Id map for a subject. So It's on your use case what maximum schema objects per subject you want to accommodate, you can give that value to identityMapCapacity.

Comment: Yeah I read about it, the problem with `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` is that it stores only those schema which are written using it, it case of reads it doesn't cache the schema.

Comment: @Explorer Late comment: Schemas are indeed cached on reads. The deserializer pulls the ID, if it already knows the schema, then it doesn't do a lookup to the registry.